# Exporting Data from Mathematica with commas

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, export

I am exporting data from mathematica in this manner to a file with "dat" extension.

```
numbercount=0;
exporttable =
   TableForm[
    Flatten[
     Table[
      Table[
       Table[{++numbercount, xcord, ycord, zcord}, {xcord, 0, 100, 5}], 
      {ycord, 0, 100, 5}], 
     {zcord,10, 100, 10}],
    2]];
Export["mydata.dat", exporttable]
```

Now what happens is the "mydata.dat" file the output appears like this

```
1  0   0   10
2  5   0   10
3  10  0   10  and so on
```

But I want the data to appear like this in the "mydata.dat" file.

```
1, 0,  0,  10
2, 5,  0,  10
3, 10, 0,  10  and so on
```

If you observer I want a comma after every first,second and third number but not after the fourth number in each line.

I have tried this code it inserts the commas between the number But it takes a long time to run as I have huge amounts of data to be exported.I also feel that someone can perhaps come up with a better solution.

```
numbercount=0;
exporttable =Flatten[
              Table[
               Table[
                Table[{++numbercount, xcord, ycord, zcord}, {xcord, 0, 100, 5}], 
               {ycord, 0, 100, 5}], 
              {zcord,10, 100, 10}], 
             2];
x = TableForm[Insert[
              exporttable[[i]], ",", {{2}, {3}, {4}}], {i, 1, Length[exporttable]}];
Export["mydata.dat", x]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried exporting it as a CSV file?  The third parameter of [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html?q=Export&lang=en) is file type, so you'd type

```
Export["mydata.dat", x, "CSV"]
```

To add to this, here is a [categorical list](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) and an [alphabetical list](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfAllFormats.html) of the available formats in Mathematica.

Comment: I couldn't believe I spend an entire day trying to figure it out

Comment: @proj_uk you should know that CSV stands for Comma Separated Values, a pretty dumb format that can be read by many programs like Excel.

Comment: @Proj_UK, I think we've all been there before, and likely to be there again. C'est le vie.

Comment: `$ExportFormats` will give you a full list of the supported formats ... but be aware that not all of them are fully supported (sorry for the word play)

Comment: @belisarius, I'd forgotten about that.  I put in the links to the docs because I can never find them when I need to.

Comment: Mma also tries to guess what format you want from the file extension, so `Export["mydata.csv", x]` will also work.

Comment: @rcollyer A link (in orange type) to the list of formats can be found just a few pixels to the right of the **headings** of the Import and Export doc pages.

Comment: @Sjoerd, and I never see it when I'm looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside note, please note that you can build your list with only one `Table` command, and **without explicit index variables**:

```
exporttable1 =  MapIndexed[Join[#2, #1] &, 
                                Flatten[Table[{xcord, ycord, zcord}, 
                                                {zcord, 10, 100, 10}, 
                                                {ycord, 0, 100, 5}, 
                                                {xcord, 0, 100, 5}], 2]]

exporttable1 == exporttable
(*
-> True
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, you had earlier also metioned it..but for some reason I comfortable andcgot used to write the table function like this

Comment: @Proj You are welcome. Please remember that using this type of construct is many times more efficient in both time and memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know abou the benefits,perhaps I will try to make it a habit of writing it the way you do.